# Closed-form notation for counting

Tags: combinatorics

If I can form sequences from $0$ or more letters of the set $\{a,b,c\}$ followed by $0$ or more digits from the set $\{0,1,2,3\}$ (repetition allowed), how can I give  a closed-form expression for the number of valid sequences of length $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have a sequence of length $k$ from $\{a,b,c\}$ followed by a sequence of length $n-k$ from $\{0,1,2,3\}$. Then we have $3^k4^{n-k}$ such sequences. Now we have to count the valid sequences for all $k$ such that $0\le k\le n$. So our answer is $$\sum_{k=0}^n3^k4^{n-k}$$

Evaluating this sum, we get $$\begin{align*}\sum_{k=0}^n3^k4^{n-k}&=\sum_{k=0}^n3^k4^{-k}4^{n}\\
&=4^n\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac34\right)^k\\
&=4^n\cdot \frac{1-\left(\frac34\right)^{n+1}}{1-\frac34}\\
&=4^{n+1}\left(1-\frac{3^{n+1}}{4^{n+1}}\right)\\
&=\boxed{4^{n+1}-3^{n+1}}\end{align*}$$

Comment: Yes, but I believe a sum is not considered to be closed form?

Comment: By most definitions, a closed-form expression is just an expression that can be evaluated in a finite number of operations. I believe a finite sum falls under this category. But my expression can be simplified, so I will edit my answer.